# Expected identifier on if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-app

***This is the whole code :)
I have been trying to fix this for an hour now, but i can still not make it.
I would be happy if someone could help me :)
Still can't make the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM code work.***

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)Collision{


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, Obstacle.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, Obstacle2.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, Bottom1.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Heli.frame, Top1.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}





}


-(void)EndGame{

if (Scorenumber > HighScore) {
    HighScore = Scorenumber;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore     
forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
}


Heli.hidden = YES;
[timer invalidate];
[Scorer invalidate];


[self performSelector:@selector(NewGame) withObject: nil afterDelay:2];

}


-(void)NewGame{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // For iPhone

Bottom1.hidden = YES;
Top1.hidden = YES;
Obstacle.hidden = YES;
Obstacle2.hidden = YES;
corona.hidden = YES;

Intro1.hidden = NO;
Intro2.hidden = NO;
Intro3.hidden = NO;

Heli.hidden = NO;
Heli.center = CGPointMake(88, 286);
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buss til app opp.png"];

Start = YES;
Scorenumber = 0;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 0"];
Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %i", HighScore];


}
 } else{
    // For iPad
    Bottom1.hidden = YES;
    Top1.hidden = YES;
    Obstacle.hidden = YES;
    Obstacle2.hidden = YES;
    corona.hidden = YES;

    Intro1.hidden = NO;
    Intro2.hidden = NO;
    Intro3.hidden = NO;

    Heli.hidden = NO;
    Heli.center = CGPointMake(153, 515);
    Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buss til app opp.png"];

    Start = YES;
    Scorenumber = 0;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 0"];
    Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %i", HighScore];
```

Comment: What's the line before it

Comment: Try adding a little more code, it might give us a better insight.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at following code:

```
-(void)NewGame{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // For iPhone

Bottom1.hidden = YES;
Top1.hidden = YES;
Obstacle.hidden = YES;
Obstacle2.hidden = YES;
corona.hidden = YES;

Intro1.hidden = NO;
Intro2.hidden = NO;
Intro3.hidden = NO;

Heli.hidden = NO;
Heli.center = CGPointMake(88, 286);
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buss til app opp.png"];

Start = YES;
Scorenumber = 0;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 0"];
Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %i", HighScore];


}
 } else{
```

and see - "`}`" symbol on line before "`} else{`" is wrong. It is the pair for

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
```

opening construction, so "else" is "standalone - it is wrong.
Try to delete this "`}`".